# Obtain Key from value javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a object that I am passing through a function. The object is as follows:

```
items: {
  'cannonball': '0',
  'cannon stand': '-9000',
  'cannon barrel': '800',
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I have the function `filterItem` defined like this:

```
function filterItem(items) {
  // console.log(items);
  var value = [];
  filteredItems = {}
  console.log(items);
  for (var key in items) {
    if (items[key] > 0 && items[key] < 1000) {
      value.push(items[key]);
    };
  };
    console.log(value);
  };
```

I am going through the object to filter through items that are between `0` and `1000` in the function. At the end of the function I would like to display the filtered key and value in an object called `filteredItems`.

How can I implement this to get the following result?

**Example output:**

```
filteredItems: {
  cannon barrel: '800'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What do you mean 'display the key of the value'?

Comment: It looks like you are keeping an array of just the value.  Why not make use of the filteredItems object, and attach them as they pass your check? `filteredItems[key] = items[key];`

Comment: value.push({key: items[key]}); ??  Instead of a simple array, make value an array of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by display, you mean console.log the object, you can make a minor modification to your function:

```js
let items = {
    'cannonball': '0',
    'cannon stand': '-9000',
    'cannon barrel': '800'
};
    
function filterItems(items) {
  filteredItems = {}
  for (var key in items) {
    if (items[key] > 0 && items[key] < 1000) {
      filteredItems[key] = items[key];
    };
  }
    console.log(filteredItems);
};
    
filterItems(items);
```

This builds up the filteredItems with the same key => value structure as the original object, and you can work with it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you could achieve this via the following:

```js
var data = {
  items: {
    "cannonball": '0',
    "cannon stand": '-9000',
    "cannon barrel": '800',
  }
}

function filterItem(items) {

  // Use Object.entries to aquire array of key/value pairs
  const filteredItems = Object.entries(items)
    .filter(([key, value]) => {
      // Filter each key/value entry by criteria 0 < value < 1000
      return parseInt(value) > 0 && parseInt(value) < 1000;
    })
    .reduce((result, [key,value]) => {
      // Use a reduction to create a hash/object with filtered key/values
      result[key] = value;      
      return result;
    }, {})

  console.log(filteredItems)
}

filterItem(data.items)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version using `Object.entries` and Array `reduce`

```js
var items = {
  'cannonball': '0',
  'cannon stand': '-9000',
  'cannon barrel': '800',
}

function filterItem(items) {
  return Object.entries(items).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (value > 0 && value < 1000) {
      acc.push({ [key]: value })
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

console.log(filterItem(items));
```